# Understanding how to construct Bruhat-Tits buildings for non-split groups by Galois descent

Tags: reference-request, buildings

Is there any way to get on top of the procedure for constructing Bruhat-Tits buildings for non-split groups over a non-archimedean local field $k$, by Galois descent, other than reading both the Bruhat-Tits articles "Groupes réductifs sur un corps local"? In particular is there any exposition which is written in English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jiu-Kang Yu has an article "Bruhat-Tits Theory and Buildings" which has appeared in  "Ottawa Lectures on Admissible Representations of Reductive $p$-adic Groups". It doesn't directly address your question, instead it contains a guide to the literature on Bruhat-Tits buildings.

There is a [26 page pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.217.9089) version of Yu's article. The published version contains a bit more information, but not a lot more (a few more references are added, plus a short introduction, plus the typesetting is updated). Unfortunately the printed version is  hard to find.

Comment: The published version shouldn't be that hard to find--most libraries should have it, and it's not a bad book to purchase.  (That said, my copy is not on hand, so I can't compare them now.)

Comment: In my experience most libraries do not have this book, and I've never seen an electronic version. Thus, hard to find.

Comment: The above link to Yu's article is not working anymore, but there is one on the Internet Archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210506181845/https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?rep=rep1&type=pdf&doi=10.1.1.217.9089

Answer (score 8):

There is a forthcoming book "Descent in buildings" by Bernhard Mühlherr, Holger Petersson and Richard Weiss, which should appear soon (published by Princeton University Press). See http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10649.html. It addresses exactly this issue, from a very building-theoretical point of view.